# Folder whatsapp

Tags: whatsapp

I restarted my Lumia720 ( Windows Phone 8.1 ) and installed whatsapp . Configured storage on the SD card .
The whatsapp not created any folder and I can not see the images and videos saved .
The phone memory is slowing down as the images / videos .
Thank you.

Comment: Did you use storage sense to configure storage on SDcard?

Comment: Whatsapp by default will save backup and media into sd card if its mounted, is your sd working fine?